# Javascript function summ with different calls

Tags: javascript

How should i make this function, that works with different calls?

See calls in alert:

```js
function summ(a){
 return function(b){
  return a+b
 }
}

alert(summ(5)(10)) //work
alert(summ(5,10)) // not work
```

Comment: Please specify in detail what you are trying to do

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Comment: check out [currying](https://google.com/search?q=currying+js)

Comment: @ShubhamTakode i want to receive a+b from function. with calls:


`summ(1,2) //return 3`
`summ(1)(2) //return 3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function summ(a,b){
  if (typeof b !== "undefined") { // check if b is present.
   return a+b;
  }
  else {  // b is not there, return another function that `capture` a 
   return function(b){
     return a+b;
    }
  }
}

alert(summ(5)(10)) // work
alert(summ(5,10))  // work
```

Basically the function `summ` you want must have to handle two different scenarios.

If `b` is not present, your function needs to return another function embedded with a value of `a`.

If `b` is present, it returns `a+b` as a normal function.